# JBOD (spanned volume) on top of RAID 0 in Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, raid0, jbod

I currently have a Windows Server 2008 R2 setup with a RAID 0 drive (2x2TB SSD) which is getting out of space.

I want to increase de available space adding more drives (probably another 2x2TB SSD) but I also need to keep the new setup under the same drive letter.

The only solution that comes to mind is to create a spanned volume (JBOD) over the two RAID 0 but I cannot find information if this is even possible.

I plan to test the former configuration as soon as I have spare drives to test. In the meantime, can anyone suggest another option?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here are my findings:

It works as expected. As the RAID 0 is at a hardware level, Windows just sees drives as it they were regular ones, so there is no problem converting them to a dynamic disk and then add more disks to create a spanned volume.

I still have to do some benchmarks to see if there is a performance hit with this setup but I expect it to be minimal or to no exist at all due the "simplicity" of spanned volumes.